# Importing csv file into elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am trying to import a huge csv file to elastic serach.Trying to use logstash for the same.
Sample csv file [Note:multiple values ]

```
Shop_name,Review_Title,Review_Text,,,,
Accord ,Excellent ,Nice Collection.,,,,,
Accord , Bad ,Not too comfortable,,,
Accord , Good ,excellent location and Staff,,,
Accord , Good ,Great Colletion,,,
Shopon,good,  staff very good ,,,
Harrisons ,Spacious,Nice Colletion
```

Logstash congiguration

```
input {
    file {
        path => ["shopreview.csv"]
        start_position => "beginning"
    }
}

filter {
    csv {
        columns => [
            "Shop_name",
            "Review_Title",
            "Review_Text"

        ]

    }
}

output {
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
    elasticsearch {
        action => "index"
        hosts => ["127.0.0.1:9200"]
        index => "reviews"
        document_type => "shopreview"
        document_id => "%{Shop_name}"
        workers => 1
    }
}
```

here when i query for review i should get all the reviews for the particular shop.

Issue
while  I query with localhost:9020/review/shopreview/Accord I am not getting all values .only 1 entry. Is the config missing something . I am little new to elk stack

Comment: It's normal since you're using the `Shop_name` as the document ID. Leave out the `document_id` parameter and you should be fine.

Comment: How do i search in that case http://localhost:9200/review/shopreview  gives "type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"No endpoint or operation is available

Comment: The correct URL for searching is `localhost:9200/review/shopreview/_search`

Comment: Thanks for the pointers!!